# Transform3D does not contain a definition for 'basis'

Tags: c#, godot, gdscript

I'm coding in C# for a Godot game. Since there aren't many tutorials on C# I'm trying to figure how I can translate this function from gdscript:

```
func _physics_process(delta):
    if shoot:
        apply_impulse(transform.basis.z, -transform,basis.z)
```

So far my bet was:

```
public override void _PhysicsProcess(double delta)
    {
        if(shoot)
        {
            ApplyImpulse(Transform.basis.z, -Transform.basis.z);
        }
    }
```

Again, the documentation doesn't help me enough to figure this error:

**'Transform3D' does not contain a definition for 'basis' and no accessible extension method 'basis' accepting a first argument of type 'Transform3D' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)**

Any help or links to documentation that might guide me would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: It's `Basis` with the capital 'B' as far as I know. The C# bindings follow C# naming conventions where public members use pascal case.

Comment: Thank you so much @hola. Thank you for reminding me the C# naming conventions. Ill try to check out more of the documentation to sort things out and update my question with your answer.